# Safari autofill defaults to wrong email address on my card

Tags: macos, safari, contacts

I'm using Safari on OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks. Anytime I fill in a form that contains an email address field, autofill selects my Evernote email address instead of my real address. This is really annoying as the Evernote address is only used for me to forward mail I want to keep to my Evernote account. I would NEVER enter that on a web form.

First address in my card is "home", second is "work" and the third is "Evernote". I have no idea why autofill would pick this one over the rest. Is it alphabetical?  Is there a way to set which specific email address gets filled in by autofill by default?